# windows explorers hangs when changing user on Vista home premium

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, freeze

I created a new user with admin priviledge on Vista i86 Home premium SP2.

And when switching to that user's account, can't launch Exploere! It says Explorerer has stopped, restart?

And so on.

Tryed the same with Guest account: same result...

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess would be a buggy shell extension, do you have 3rd party shell extensions or tweaks installed?

If you have a empty desktop, use Ctrl+Alt+Del and get a instance of taskmanager, then start your browser (Menu: File->New task)

Download [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and/or [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) (Logon and Explorer tabs) and disable non-Microsoft items that you don't recognize or don't need.

If this is a Microsoft bug, hopefully sending in [error reports](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Reporting-and-solving-computer-problems) will solve it at some point in the future.